# Unknown python expression filename=r'/path/to/file'

Tags: python, string

I found this potentially very useful python [script](http://quickscriptfixes.blogspot.co.uk/), but came across these expressions which I've never seen before:

```
inputfilename = r'/path/to/infile'
outputfilename = r'/path/to/outfile'
```

I can't find a way to search for it. what does the `r'...'` do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a "raw string," see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation). Often used to be able to write special characters (e.g. `\`) without escaping.

Comment: r is a raw string literal which enables you to forget about the escape sequences! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517802/python-raw-literal-string

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in this case, but if the path had backslashes you would want to include the `r`

Comment: Thanks everyone! And yes, the posted link also answers my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `r'..'` string modifier causes the `'..'` string to be interpreted **literally**. That means, `r'My\Path\Without\Escaping'` will evaluate to `'My\Path\Without\Escaping'` - without causing the backslash to escape characters. The prior is equivalent to `'My\\Path\\Without\\Escaping'` string, but without the raw modifier.

Note: The string **cannot** end with an odd number of backslashes, i.e `r'Bad\String\Example\'` is not a correct string.

Comment: ...with one exception: `r'My\Path\Without\Escaping\'` doesn't work. Even raw strings may not end in an odd number of backslashes.

Comment: @MaciejGol - So the folder depth needs to be an even number for this to work!?

Comment: @DavidR, it has nothing to do with the folder depth. It's all about whether being forced to use double slashes `\\ ` without `r` modifier, or single slashes `\\ ` with `r` modifier.

Answer (score 3):

It's called raw string literal.

According to [`Python String literals documentation`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed
>   with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use
>   different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.
>
> ...
>
> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings
>   are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C

Answer (score 2):

It just means *raw string* in Python. Meaning that whatever is inside the string, is the string. For example, if you wanted to add slashes:

```
string1 = "happy\/cheese"
```

You would need to add `\` in front of the slash since its an escaping character. For example, `\n` means a new line.

If you keep the string raw, it makes sure that whatever is in the string is not interpreted a special way. for example if you wrote `string2 = r"\n"`, it would just give you `"\n"` as you string, and not a new line.

You can learn more about them, from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Now, this is done in your case, because file paths have a lot of slashes, and we'd like to avoid having to put in so many backslashes.