# Different file name when saving in loop python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following lines of code to loop over different files in a folder:

```
import os

files_in_folder_1 = [os.path.join(path1, f) for f in os.listdir(path1) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path1, f))]

files_in_folder_2 = [os.path.join(path2, f) for f in os.listdir(path2) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, f))]

for file1, file2 in zip(files_in_folder_1, files_in_folder_2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:

        dftask = pd.read_csv(file2)
        dfresource = pd.read_csv(file1)
```

At the end of all operations I want to save the files in **another directory** with the **same filename**. However how should I do that? I use this:

```
dftask.to_csv(r'path\file1.csv')
dfresource.to_csv(r'path\file2.csv')
```

However when using this line of code the csv. file is constantly overwritten inside the loop over all files.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) will give you the file name just join it to the new path and save it however you want:

```
new_dir = "path/to/dir/"
for file1, file2 in zip(files_in_folder_1, files_in_folder_2):
    dftask = pd.read_csv(file2)
    dfresource = pd.read_csv(file1)
    # work on df's  .......

    # save to new dir   
    dftask.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dir,os.path.basename(file2)))
    dfresource.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dir,os.path.basename(file1)))
```

If you are using file.open to open the files first you can get the name from the .name attribute:

```
new_dir = "path/to/dir/"
for file1, file2 in zip(files_in_folder_1, files_in_folder_2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
        dftask = pd.read_csv(file2)
        dfresource = pd.read_csv(file1)

    dftask.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dir, file2.name))
    dfresource.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dir,file1.name))
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: 

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename

Comment: This line: dftask.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dir,os.path.basename(file2)))

Comment: filename: "r'path\\Tasks-Job--16kvZ-Feike_15min_data-201728.csv"

Comment: why is there an `r` there? Anyway what does `print os.path.join(new_dir,os.path.basename(file2)` output?

Comment: I used this same 'r before when pointing to a directory, so I thaught it was necessary. But I tried it without the 'r and it returns the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034822/unknown-python-expression-filename-r-path-to-file

Comment: You don't need `r`, os.path.join takes care of that

Comment: Print gives: D:-path\Tasks-Job--16kvxZ-Feike_15min_data-20150728.csv

Comment: you should try putting the full path in, just to be sure. You are probably trying to create a file in a driectory that does not exist, at least in reference to where the code is executing. Try ```new_dir = 'C:\Users\whoever\whatever\path'```

Comment: and what is in `D:-path`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that is weird indeed, however in the code I type D:\ path so I do not understand that it prints this D:-path

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you can use `'path\' + file1.name.split("/")[-1]` to save all files with original names.

Answer (score 0):

With the above code when the loop exits `file1` and `file2` each will contain individual DataFrame from last iteration of the loop.

If you want to consolidate all the DataFrames should create list containing each of the individual DataFrames and concat them.

```
import os

files_in_folder_1 = [os.path.join(path1, f) for f in os.listdir(path1) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path1, f))]

files_in_folder_2 = [os.path.join(path2, f) for f in os.listdir(path2) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, f))]

dftask_list = []
dfresource_list = []
for file1, file2 in zip(files_in_folder_1, files_in_folder_2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:

        dftask_list.append(pd.read_csv(file2))
        dfresource_list.append(pd.read_csv(file1))

dftask = pd.concat(dftask_list)
dfresource = pd.concat(dfresource_list)
```

Note: You may need to reset index after this.

```
dftask = dftask.reset_index(drop=True)
dfresource = dfresource.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) , the function returns a tuple, where the second element would be the filename . Example -

```
f1name = os.path.split(file1)[1]
f2name = os.path.split(file2)[1]
```

Then you can use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join it with the other directory and get the resultant path. Example -

```
file1newpath = os.path.join(otherdir, os.path.split(file1)[1])
file2newpath = os.path.join(otherdir, os.path.split(file2)[1])
```

Then you can use the above names to save the file -

```
dftask.to_csv(file1newpath)
dfresource.to_csv(file2newpath)
```

---

Demo for `os.path.split()` -

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.split(r'C:\Users\temp\somedir\somefile.csv')[1]
'somefile.csv'
```