# Python glob path issue

Tags: python, glob

I have a question about using glob in python.

I want to know why the path is showing backslashes instead of a forward slash?

Example being C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Pythonfiles\excel.xlsx

My script is

```
import glob
excel_list = (glob.glob("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Pythonfiles/*.xlsx"))
```

This is my output I'm getting:

```
['C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19282.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19557.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19667.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19742.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\CEImport.xlsx']
```

Any help would be great thank you

Comment: If you use forward slash you do not need to use double slash or the [r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034822/unknown-python-expression-filename-r-path-to-file)

Comment: Can you please post the full output you are receiving?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: `glob` ultimately uses `os.path.join` to create a file path consisting of `C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Pythonfiles` and `foo.xlsx`. If `os.path.sep` is a backslash, that's what gets used, regardless of what appears in the argument. Also, the argument is only broken down into its constituent directories as necessary to isolate any "magic" characters.

Comment: @Greg

This is the output I get:

['C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19282.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19557.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19667.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\19742.xlsx', 'C:/Users/Name/Desktop/PythonFiles\\CEImport.xlsx']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python), '/' and '\' are interchangeable in python file paths.

Comment: Gotcha the slashes ended up not being an issue thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`\` and `/` are interchangeable path separators, but if you wanted to normalize the paths so they are uniform, use [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase)

```py
excel_path = [os.path.normpath(i) for i in glob.glob("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Pythonfiles/*.xlsx")]

#output
['C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\PythonFiles\\19282.xlsx',
 'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\PythonFiles\\19557.xlsx',
 'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\PythonFiles\\19667.xlsx',
 'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\PythonFiles\\19742.xlsx',
 'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\PythonFiles\\CEImport.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the double backslashes (`\\`) on the string path because you are under Windows, which uses a single backslash (`\`) instead of a single slash (`/`). Please, note that `\\` is the same as `\`, since backslash is used for especial characters.

Also, as mentioned by [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010742/5219160), a backslash `\` and slash `/` are interchangeable in python file paths, thus you shouldn't worry about them.