# How do I read Excel file in python using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have installed pandas package in pycharm, trying to read an excel file but it is showing error.

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Here are my codes I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
Book1 = pd.read_excel(File_path="C:\Users\shubh\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
print(Book1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace `\` with `\\`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `r:` in front of your code, and replace backward slash with forward slash:

```
Book1 = pd.read_excel(File_path=r"C:/Users/shubh/Desktop/Book1.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

There are loads of sources to read from about what `r:` does to your path.

The `r'..'` string modifier causes the '..' string to be interpreted literally. That means, `r'My\Path\Without\Escaping'` will evaluate to `'My\Path\Without\Escaping'` - without causing the backslash to escape characters. The prior is equivalent to `'My\\Path\\Without\\Escaping'` string, but without the raw modifier.

Note: The string cannot end with an odd number of backslashes, i.e `r'Bad\String\Example\'` is not a correct string.

Taken from:
[Unknown python expression filename=r'/path/to/file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034822/unknown-python-expression-filename-r-path-to-file)

Comment: Can you explain what the `r` is doing there as well, that would make this a more helpful answer

Comment: Thanks but didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "" for "/" in Your path