# "image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar" from cv2

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:

```
import cv2
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cam.set(3,640)
cam.set(4,480)
detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\8f51e58ac0813cb695f3733926c77f52- 
07eed8d5486b1abff88d7e34891f1326a9b6a6f5\\8f51e58ac0813cb695f3733926c77f52- 
07eed8d5486b1abff88d7e34891f1326a9b6a6f5\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
face_id=input("Enter a numeric face id: ")
print("taking sample, look at camera......")
count=0
while True:
      ret, img=cam.read('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\leo software 
      company\\gamedata\\.vscode\\Maya.Ai')
      converted_image=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      faces=detector.detectMultiScale(converted_image, 1.3, 5)
      for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
          cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
          count += 1
          cv2.imwrite("samples/face."+str(face_id)+'.'+str(count)+".jpg", 
          converted_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
          cv2.imshow('image',img)
          k=cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff
          if k == 27:
          break
         elif count>=10:
         break
         print("id made succesfully")
         cam.release()
         cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\leo software company\game data\.vscode\Maya.Ai\id.py", line 10, in <module>
    ret, img=cam.read('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\leo software company\\game data\\.vscode\\Maya.Ai')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'read'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'image'
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look at the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) from the documentation. You can initialize your `VideoCapture` to read from a connected camera (as you have done) or from a saved file, as it appears that you intend. After creating the `VideoCapture` object, its `read` method doesn't require any arguments, it just grabs the next frame.

So you probably want something like:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(
      r'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\leo software company\gamedata\.vscode\Maya.Ai',
      cv2.CAP_DSHOW
)
```

And then:

```
ret, img = cam.read()
```

Also: The way you show your strings split across lines would throw a `SyntaxError`, so your actual code must not look like that. And you can use a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034822/unknown-python-expression-filename-r-path-to-file) to avoid needing to double all your backslashes for Windows file paths.